# What is the best way to approach a JSON API output and a v-model within Vue3

Tags: vuejs3

I did build a form with Element Plus (https://element-plus.org/#/en-US/component/select). Specific: Basic Multiple Select.

The problem I have is that the Element Plus element () works with v-model. From the API I retrieve the following output in JSON: `[1, 2]` which is fieldData[field.field].

If I use v-model, it won't work as v-model does not accept JSON I think. The selected options aren't visible. How can I JSON parse in V-model or do I need to fix it otherwise?

```html
<el-form label-position="top">
  <el-form-item :label="field.label">
    <el-select
      v-model="fieldData[field.field]"
      multiple
      placeholder="Select"
      @change="changed(field.field, value2, field.validation)"
      style="width: 100%"
      clearable
    >
      <el-option
        v-for="item in getOptions(field.options.link, field.options.field)"
        :key="item.value"
        :label="item.label"
        :value="item.value"
      >
      </el-option>
    </el-select>
  </el-form-item>
</el-form>
```

If I change the code to: `v-model="value2"` and add data to the component (check below) it is working.

```js
data() {
  return {
    value2: [1, 2]
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

JSON is not a *type*, it's a *format*, so I"m assuming you mean JSON-encoded object, which is a `string`

You can (and I believe should) parse the data before passing it to your template

The easiest way to do that is to pass the data through a computed that can then create an array that can be used by the template.

So if the `fieldData` is an array of JSON-encoded string, you could do this

```js
computed:{
  fieldDataformated(){
    return this.fieldData.map(str => JSON.parse(str))
  }
},
```

and then use it as `v-model="fieldDataformated[field.field]"` (assuming field.field` is an index).

If `this.fieldData` is an object, the computed would look a little different, but the same idea, iterate over the fields and convert the string to an object;

You should also consider resolving `getOptions(field.options.link, field.options.field)` as a computed as-well (`options[field.options.link][field.options.field]`‍♂️), since method look-ups in the template will force the view renderer to recalculate the values every time anything changes on the component. Having the value cached by a computed will reduce the load on the browser/js.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried to create an computed function. When I refresh my console tells me the following: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.fieldData.map is not a function`

Comment: then it's not an array, maybe an object‍♂️, in which case you can use `Object.keys` or `values` or `entries` to loop